# Updating phpMyAdmin to latest 4.2.11 version on MAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp, osx-yosemite, updating

I have downloaded the latest version of MAMP. It includes the latest PHP version but does not include the latest version of phpMyAdmin. Make sense to you?...me neither. 
In order to assist me you will need to see the short and seeming easy upgrade instructions. You will find those  [here](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html).
I am unable to locate the "appsolute" directory of the "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php" path. Can't find it in "MacintoshHD/Library/Application Support" or the "Users/username/Library/Application Support."
The "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin" path starting at step 5 is no problem but seems like a secondary step required after steps 1 - 4.
Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone but it seams the "appsolute" directory only exists if you have MAMP Pro installed and configured.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help anyone but it seams the "appsolute" directory only exists if you have MAMP Pro installed and configured. So you can pretty much just follow the instructions to copy the `config.inc.php` file from MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin into the downloaded folder of your new phpMyAdmin version and replace your old phpMyAdmin directory with the new one containing the old `config.inc.php`.